# Variable Explorer Spyder

Tags: listview, python-3.x, variables, numpy

my following code works absolutely right and I even get an output, but the centroids_listoflists does not appear in the variable explorer nor can I recall it with print(centroids_listoflists).

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.choice(2,size=(10, 5))
centroids=data[np.random.choice(data.shape[0], 2)]
#We have random binary data; here 10 observation vectors with length 5
#Out of these data we choose randomly 2 centroids to work with
print ("Here are the centroids:")
print (centroids)
print ("Here is the data:")
print (data)

distance_array =np.full((data.shape[0],2),data.shape[1])
distance_array[:,1]=0
distance_array=distance_array.astype(np.int)

#determine the hamming distance to each centroid and save the smallest one

def compare(centroids,data):
    for a in range(data.shape[0]):
        for b in range(centroids.shape[0]):
            distance = 0
            for i in range(data.shape[1]):
                if (data[a][i] != centroids[b][i]):
                    distance +=1
                else:
                    distance +=0
            if (distance <= distance_array[a,0]):
                distance_array[a,0] = distance
                distance_array[a,1] = b
            else:
                pass

compare(centroids,data)

print ("Here are the distances:")
print (distance_array)

#create a LookupTable which tells me which centroid contains which vectors and with what distance

def create_centroids_listoflists(data,distance_array,centroids):
    centroids_listoflists = [ [] for i in range(centroids.shape[0])]
    for a in range(len(centroids_listoflists)):
        for b in range(len(distance_array)):
            if (a == distance_array[b,1]):
                centroids_listoflists[a].append((distance_array[b,1],data[b]))
            else:
                pass
    print(centroids_listoflists)

print ("LookupTable for centroid,data and distance:")            
create_centroids_listoflists(data,distance_array,centroids)
```

Would be glad if you could tell me why its not working...
I think there is something wrong in the part for the definition of the function create_centroids_listoflists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but if you create a variable inside the function, it will be a local variable and thus you cannot recall it afterwards. I solved the problem by initializing the list(or the variable) before entering the defined function. Then it will be saved as a global variable and is also available in the variable explorer.

Best regards and thanks für your help.

Answer (score 0):

The varaible is created inside the function, and doesn't exist outside of the function. You should use the `return` statement to send it outside of your function:

```
def create_centroids_listoflists(data,distance_array,centroids):
    centroids_listoflists = [ [] for i in range(centroids.shape[0])]
    for a in range(len(centroids_listoflists)):
        for b in range(len(distance_array)):
            if (a == distance_array[b,1]):
                centroids_listoflists[a].append((distance_array[b,1],data[b]))
            else:
                pass
    return centroids_listoflists

print ("LookupTable for centroid,data and distance:")            
centroids_listoflists = create_centroids_listoflists(data,distance_array,centroids)
print(centroids_listoflists)
```

Note that `centroids_listoflists` is not the same variable inside and outside of the function, but it's set to the same value (the list of lists)